# Named entity recognition in Spacy

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I am trying to find Named entities for a sentence as below

```
import spacy.lang.en
parser = spacy.lang.en.English()
ParsedSentence = parser(u"Alphabet is a new startup in China")
for Entity in  ParsedSentence.ents:  
    print (Entity.label, Entity.label_, ' '.join(t.orth_ for t in Entity))
```

I am expecting to get the result "Alphabet","China" but I am getting an empty set as result. What am I doing wrong here

Comment: NER is based on training input data. Therefore, for your example, it might not know from the limited context that "Alphabet" is a `named entity`. Try more examples.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per spacy [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#101) for Name Entity Recognition here is the way to extract name entity

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en') # install 'en' model (python3 -m spacy download en)
doc = nlp("Alphabet is a new startup in China")
print('Name Entity: {0}'.format(doc.ents))
```

**Result**
`Name Entity:  (China,)`

To make "Alphabet" a 'Noun' append it with "The".

```
doc = nlp("The Alphabet is a new startup in China")
print('Name Entity: {0}'.format(doc.ents))
```

`Name Entity:  (Alphabet, China)`

Comment: But if the input sentence was `I love biscuits, chocolate and bicyles.`, shouldn't the `PRODUCT` entity be identified (for `biscuits`, `chocolate` and `bicycles`)? The [doc](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#named-entities) suggests `PRODUCT` is for food, vehicles, etc. However, `doc.ents` doesn't identify any entity.

Answer (score 1):

In Spacy version 3 the Transformers from Hugging Face are fine-tuned to the operations that Spacy provided in previous versions, but with better results.

> Transformers are currently (2020) the state-of-art in Natural Language Processing, i.e generally we had (one-hot-encode -> word2vec -> glove | fast text) then (recurrent neural network, recursive neural network, gated recurrent unit, long short-term memory, bi-directional long short-term memory, etc) and now Transformers + Attention (BERT, RoBERTa, XLNet, XLM, CTRL, AlBERT, T5, Bart, GPT, GPT-2, GPT-3) - This is just to give context for 'why' you should consider Transformers, I know that there are lots of stuff that I didn't mention like Fuzz, Knowledge Graph and so on

Install the dependencies:

```sh
sudo apt install libncurses5
```

```sh
pip install spacy-transformers --pre -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

```sh
pip install spacy-nightly # I'm using 3.0.0rc2
```

Download a model:

```sh
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf # English Transformer pipeline, Roberta base
```

Here's a [list](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases) of available models.

And then use it as you would normally do:

```py
import spacy


text = 'Type something here which can be related to something, e.g Stack Over Flow organization'

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

document = nlp(text)

print(document.ents)
```

References:

Learn about [Transformers and Attention](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Bdc55j80l8).

Read a summary about the different [Trasnformers architectures](https://huggingface.co/transformers/summary.html).

Learn about the [Transformers fine-tune](https://nightly.spacy.io/usage/embeddings-transformers) done by Spacy.